# Cropping Image in Android (Crop Intent)

Tags: android, image, crop, android-crop

I used this [code](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/07/how-to-crop-image-from-camera-and.html) to use android's built in image crop tools. My code is the following

```
 public void takePicture(){
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
        takePictureIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        takePictureIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imageViewImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

    }
}
```

takePicture is called inside a click listener for a Button. What is done is I can open android camera take the picture and when hitting save the image is saved on my imageView. But no cropping activity appears, plus the image on imageView looks awfull. The quality is like it's pixelated. Am I doing something wrong? I used a Samsung galaxy tab 3 to test my app

EDIT using the answer bellow...Stil not working

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Log.d("onActivityResult", "Inside on activity for result");
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imageViewImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        fileUri = getImageUri(this, imageBitmap);χ
        cropImage();
    }else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CROP && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap)extras.get("data");
        imageViewImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);


    }
}

 public void takePicture(){
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){

        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

}

 public void cropImage() {
    try {

        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

        cropIntent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CROP);
    }
    // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        // display an error message
        String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

[LocCat here](http://pastebin.com/Wt43zvnk)

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are [many image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45?sort=created). Please use one.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this.

```
private void doCrop(Uri picUri) {
    try {

        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");           
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");           
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);           
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);           
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_PIC_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        // display an error message
        String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Get Uri from bitmap

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
  String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
  return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Declare

`final int CROP_PIC_REQUEST_CODE = 1;`

Than simply

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CROP_PIC_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (data != null) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap bitmap= extras.getParcelable("data");
            yourImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: will this replace my takePicture function? What does picUri stands for? I haven't saved Image yet.

Comment: you need to pass the save image uri, this will open a crop intent (if available) and you can perform  cropping.

Comment: Yes where is image saved by default?After I receive it back from Activity for Result, I just place it on the ImageView but not saving it anywhere. I know it's saved on my Gallery, but still can't get it to save it where I want

Comment: when you open a camera intent, it will save you picture in gallery

Comment: Updated wth part of logCat.

Comment: there is no log cat. Log cat is a debug log

Comment: I know, I pasted a part of the logcat output that I got from using android monitor

Comment: forcefully go to ImageCrop()

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain i had one question in mind that, why do we need to implement imageUri method? and is it only during we use sharedpreferences? .. would appreciate if i can get any explanation.

Comment: Bitmap we are getting are being saved in Gallery of your Device. Hence we need the full path or URI to further use it

Comment: The recommended intent action in this answer is not part of standard Android. It won't work on some number of devices, see https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html