# How to crop ( cut) automatically image taken from custom camera as specific frame

Tags: android

I am creating a custom camera app . I want to the taken image 's cropped as specific frame ( in my app , it's a drawable file ) , it's similar like this ( sorry , i can post image ) :

This is main UI of camera app :
http://i.imgur.com/fY1Wk1D.jpg
and the result is :
http://i.imgur.com/S2Md7K6.jpg

Any idea ?? I have search around but it's seem i can't find the right answer. Thanks!!

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294252/cropping-image-in-android-crop-intent)

Comment: But how can i get the size of the frame ( in this case , it 's drawble file ).