# failed to call intent (camera.action.CROP) on AVD(API Level 31) without any exception msg

Tags: android, action, crop, photo, google-photos

My code ia as below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
     grantUriPermission(getPackageName(),mImageCaptureUri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
     grantUriPermission(getPackageName(),mImageCropUri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
}
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 480);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 480);
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    intent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCropUri);

              intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
              intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
              intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
              intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);

try {
      startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

1. The test environment is AVD(API Level 31). It should have a default crop app, Google Photo.
   And my code about taking photo works fine.
2. When running my app, I select a .jpg file from Downloads folder, and then call intent camera.action.CROP). But the code doesn't take effect at all.
3. I checked the two uri in logcat,

mImageCaptureUri = content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F71/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fpng/1987893059

mImageCropUri = content://com.myapp.fileprovider/my_pic/Pictures/tmp_kuilimar_16712596169354514375851720661420.jpg

In addition, I can't get any exception message in LogCat with e.printStackTrace().

So, what's wrong? ...... Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html).

> It should have a default crop app, Google Photo

There is no requirement for any device, let alone any user of any device, to have an app that supports your undocumented and unsupported `Intent` action. And there is no requirement for Google Photo, or any other particular app, to support that undocumented and unsupported `Intent` action.

There are [many image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45?sort=created). Please use one.

Comment: Probably got it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27294293/9473786), which has enough upvotes to suggest that it at least sometimes works (or used to).

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue resulted from the grantUriPermission(). We should grant Uri Permission to Google Photo, which will preform CROP, other than the app self.
Thank you all.